# Prevent XSS and SQL injection in chat

Tags: php, sql, xss

im new with php and website coding, but I would like to know how can I make an input field for a chat so that its not vulnerable for xss and sql but characters like ? and ! are usable.

the coding I use to prevent sql injection :

```
real_escape_string($_POST['message']);
```

now is that enough for sql injection and how can I prevent XSS?

Comment: For SQL Injection learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: @JayBlanchard Okey, that seems pretty simple indeed, now do I need to rewrite all of my statements or only the one that uses user input as a value?

Comment: If you're going to do one, you should do the other for consistencies sake.

Comment: @Nick Better not to use any `mysql_` at all (This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0)